# SP 2013 - Page Layout changes not reflected - O365

Tags: page-layout, office-365, design-manager

I'm trying to create a customer page layout using Design Manager on a 2013 on Ofice 365 site.

I created the page layout using a custom content type, opened the html in VS 2013 and added all snippets I required, saved and published it.

None of the changes are reflected on to the associated aspx page. This happens many times but usually I used to delete the page layout and recreate it and publish would work.

I have tried to check out and publish multiple times but resultant aspx page doesn't have any webpart snippets but only the webpart zones I copied are saved on to aspx.

I have no clue why it does behave this way, any comments would be appreciated.

Comment: Try creating a new page using the layout and check the changes are available. Also you can directly open the pagelayout from the browser and review whether the changes are there or not.

Comment: I have tried creating new page but changes aren't there.

Comment: Its really strange, if I open the aspx in SPD 2013 I can see the snippet code was converted successfully but if I open the same in VS 2013 it doesn't have the code. I tried opening the html file in browser and it doesn't have any of my snippet. Its a real pain, I'm not sure anybody has experienced the same in O365 or on prem while working with Page Layouts.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint Content pages take the layout and creates a copy in the content database with the custom layout design available at the time of  creation. This is now stored in database. When the custom layout is modified and redeployed, only the layout get affected and not the content. Page layouts while deployed only carry web part zones and not the web parts with content. You have write an event receiver to add web-part to web-part zone on future activation or use a power shell script

Comment: You probably didn't read my post properly because I'm doing this using Designer Manager and you can insert snippets with webpart content it the layout pages.

Comment: Have you applied all the web.config changes requires for the webpart, if you are missing anything, the content may not render, make sure you add all the tags properly

Comment: do you know that we cannot access web.config file on a Office 365 tenant site??